# c# different MD5 instance cause hash collision

Tags: c#, hash, md5

I have about 16,000,000 urls, and I want to get hashcode about the urls.
I use System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 to create hashcode, refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx)

my code like this：

```
    private string createMD5(string input)
    {
            using(MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())//the problem is here
            {
                 byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
                 byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                 for(int i = 0;i < hashBytes.Length;i ++)
                 {
                     sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
                 }
                 return sb.ToString();
            }        
    }
    public void checkMD5Hash()
    {

        HashSet<string> urls = new HashSet<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:/ScopePractice/SatoriExtractionReport/TransformData/WikipediaUrlList.tsv"))
        {
            //calcuate the MD5 hashcode for all urls
            HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();
            string line = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                set.Add(createMD5(line));
            }
            double totalNum = 15844272;
            Console.WriteLine("MD5Hash: {0}",set.Count() * 1.0 / totalNum * 1.0);
        }
    }
```

I use `using(MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())`,so I create many MD5 instances, it causes difference urls get same MD5 hashcode.

after that, I change my code, use the same MD5 instance to generate hashcode and the problem is solved.

```
    static MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
    private string createMD5(string input)
    {

            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0;i < hashBytes.Length;i ++)
            {
                sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();



    }
```

But I don't why different instance will cause this problem, please help me, thanks.

Comment: If you want a unique identifier then use a sequential number or a GUID. Hashes are meant to verify that a piece of data has not been altered (repudiation) or that 2 pieces of data are the same (like passwords) and were not designed to serve as a unique identifier. Also a note on MD5, it is considered obsolete and not secure so do not use it for anything security related.

Comment: Can you give example of two string (url's) that generates the same MD5 hash ?

Comment: I save all the urls to database, when I get a new url, first I want to check whether the url has already existed in the database. If I use the raw url to check, it will waste a lot of time, so I use hashcode to help me check the url.